# below calculation work in API?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

i created checkoutpage then it contain total,payment due and payment balance. If give total it show the payment due amount & payment balance amount in mobile app. But it doesn't update  the browser?

```
public class FinalCheckOutActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private AQuery mAQuery;
    private TransparentProgressDialog mTransparentProgressDialog;
    private String mStrCheckOut = "", mStrGEtData = "", mStrAddressData = "", mStrPaypAl = "";
    private Spinner mSpnDefualtAddress, mSpnShipAddress;
    private Button mBtnPlaceOrder;
    private CheckBox mChBxSameAddres, mChkBxDiffAddress, mChkBoxAccept;
    private RadioButton mRdoPayPal, mRdoCash;
    private RadioGroup mRdoGroupPay;
    private ImageView mIvBack;
    private TextView mTvAddAddress, mTvSubTot, mTvDiscount, mTVGrandTot, mTvPendingAmt, mTvPayNow, mIvAddAddress;
    private ArrayList<SpinnerData> mArrayListAddres;
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayoutShiipingMethod, mLinearLayoutPayMethod, mLinearLayoutOrderDetails;
    private RadioGroup mRbnOptionshippingmethods;
    private ArrayList<UserAddressData> mArrayListshippingMethod;
    private ArrayList<UserAddressData> mArrayListPaymentMethods;
    private String shippingMethodId;
    private RadioGroup mRbnOptionPaymentMethods;
    private String shippingPaymentID;
    private View viewOrderData;
    private JSONObject mJsonObject, jsonObjectData;
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayoutTabShiping;
    private RadioButton newRadioButton;
    private ArrayList<SpinnerData> mArrayListBilign;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_check_out);


        //setUI();
    }

    private void setUI() {
        mAQuery = new AQuery(this);
        mTransparentProgressDialog = new TransparentProgressDialog(this, R.drawable.ic_loader_image);
        mSpnDefualtAddress = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_default_address);
        mSpnShipAddress = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_ship_address);

        mBtnPlaceOrder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_place_order);

        mRdoGroupPay = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdo_payment);
        mRdoCash = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdo_cash);
        mRdoPayPal = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdo_paypal);

        mLinearLayoutTabShiping = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_shiping);

        mChBxSameAddres = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_ship_to_same_address);
        mChkBxDiffAddress = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_diff_ship_address);
        mChkBoxAccept = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_acceept);
        mLinearLayoutShiipingMethod = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_shipping_method);
        mLinearLayoutPayMethod = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_payment_method);
        mLinearLayoutOrderDetails = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lv_shipping_order_view);
        mIvAddAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.img_add_address);
        mTvSubTot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_subtotal);
        mTvDiscount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_discount);
        mTVGrandTot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_grand_tot);
        mTvPendingAmt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_pending_pay);
        mTvPayNow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_payable_now);
        mIvBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back_one_page);
        mArrayListAddres = new ArrayList<>();
        mArrayListshippingMethod = new ArrayList<>();
        mArrayListPaymentMethods = new ArrayList<>();
        mArrayListBilign = new ArrayList<>();
        mBtnPlaceOrder.setOnClickListener(this);
        mIvAddAddress.setOnClickListener(this);
//        mTvAddAddress.setOnClickListener(this);
        mIvBack.setOnClickListener(this);



        ajaxCallback.setTimeout(Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.ajax_timeout)));
        mChBxSameAddres.setChecked(true);
        mLinearLayoutTabShiping.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mChBxSameAddres.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {

                    mLinearLayoutTabShiping.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //mSpnShipAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    // perform logic
                }

            }
        });

        mChkBxDiffAddress.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    mChBxSameAddres.setChecked(false);
                    mLinearLayoutTabShiping.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        SpinnerData data = new SpinnerData();
        data.setmStrName("Select Address");
        mArrayListAddres.add(data);
        mSpnDefualtAddress.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(this, mArrayListAddres));
        getFinalCheckOutData();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUI();
        //getAddressData();
    }

    /**
     * get user address web service call
     **/
    private void getAddressData() {
        mStrAddressData = getString(R.string.WS_HOST) + getString(R.string.WS_GET_MULTIPLE_ADDRESS);
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("customer_id", SessionClass.getUserId(this));
        Log.e("Hash map final data", "Hash map->" + hashMap.toString());
        if (AvailableNetwork.isConnectingToInternet(this)) {
            mAQuery.progress(mTransparentProgressDialog).ajax(mStrAddressData, hashMap, JSONObject.class, ajaxCallback);
        } else {
           // showAlert(getString(R.string.no_internt_connection), -1);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(MainActivity.coordinatorLayout, R.string.no_internt_connection, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            //setUI(view);
                        }
                    });

            // Changing message text color
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
            // Changing action button text color
            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) sbView.getLayoutParams();
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            sbView.setLayoutParams(params);
            TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            snackbar.show();
        }


    }

    /**
     * get user address web service call
     **/
    private void getPaypalData() {
        mStrPaypAl = getString(R.string.WS_HOST) + getString(R.string.WS_PAYPAL);
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("order_increment_id", orderID);
        Log.e("Hash map final data", "Hash map->" + hashMap.toString());
        if (AvailableNetwork.isConnectingToInternet(this)) {
            mAQuery.progress(mTransparentProgressDialog).ajax(mStrPaypAl, hashMap, JSONObject.class, ajaxCallback);
        } else {
           // showAlert(getString(R.string.no_internt_connection), -1);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(MainActivity.coordinatorLayout, R.string.no_internt_connection, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            //setUI(view);
                        }
                    });

            // Changing message text color
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
            // Changing action button text color
            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) sbView.getLayoutParams();
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            sbView.setLayoutParams(params);
            TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            snackbar.show();
        }


    }

    /**
     * Get final checkout data
     **/
    private void getFinalCheckOutData() {
        mStrGEtData = getString(R.string.WS_HOST) + getString(R.string.WS_FINAL_CHECKOUT_DETAIls);
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("cart_id", IntermediateCheckoutActivity.cartId);
        Log.e("Hash map final data", "Hash map->" + hashMap.toString());
        if (AvailableNetwork.isConnectingToInternet(this)) {
            mAQuery.progress(mTransparentProgressDialog).ajax(mStrGEtData, hashMap, JSONObject.class, ajaxCallback);
        } else {
           // showAlert(getString(R.string.no_internt_connection), -1);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(MainActivity.coordinatorLayout, R.string.no_internt_connection, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            //setUI(view);
                        }
                    });

            // Changing message text color
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
            // Changing action button text color
            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) sbView.getLayoutParams();
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            sbView.setLayoutParams(params);
            TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            snackbar.show();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Place order web service call
     **/

    private void placeOrder() {
        mStrCheckOut = getString(R.string.WS_HOST) + getString(R.string.WS_PLACE_ORDER);
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("cart_id", IntermediateCheckoutActivity.cartId);
        hashMap.put("checkoutdetails", jsonObjectData.toString());
        Log.e("Place order", "hash map-->" + hashMap.toString());
        if (AvailableNetwork.isConnectingToInternet(this)) {
            mAQuery.progress(mTransparentProgressDialog).ajax(mStrCheckOut, hashMap, JSONObject.class, ajaxCallback);
        } else {
            //showAlert(getString(R.string.no_internt_connection), -1);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(MainActivity.coordinatorLayout, R.string.no_internt_connection, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            //setUI(view);
                        }
                    });

            // Changing message text color
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
            // Changing action button text color
            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) sbView.getLayoutParams();
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            sbView.setLayoutParams(params);
            TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkValidationn() {
        if (mSpnDefualtAddress.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
            showAlert("Please select billing address first.", -1);
            mSpnDefualtAddress.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } else if (mRbnOptionshippingmethods.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
            showAlert("Please select shipping method first.", -1);
            mRbnOptionshippingmethods.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } else if (mRdoGroupPay.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
            showAlert("Please select payment method first.", -1);
            mRdoGroupPay.requestFocus();
            return false;
        } else if (!mChkBoxAccept.isChecked()) {
            showAlert("Please select terms and conditions first.", -1);
            mChkBoxAccept.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void showAlert(String message, final int flg) {
        AlertDialog.Builder aBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        aBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        aBuilder.setMessage(message);
        aBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                setNxtFlg(flg);
            }
        });
        aBuilder.create();
        aBuilder.show();
    }

    private void setNxtFlg(int flg) {

        switch (flg) {
            case 3:
                Intent intent = new Intent(FinalCheckOutActivity.this, PayPalPaymentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", urlMain);
                intent.putExtra("order_id", orderID);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_left_in, R.anim.anim_left_out);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(FinalCheckOutActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("key", "4");
                startActivity(intent1);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_left_in, R.anim.anim_left_out);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_place_order:
                getCheckOutData();
                if (checkValidationn()) {
                    placeOrder();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.img_back_one_page:
                onBackPressed();
                //finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_left_in, R.anim.anim_left_out);
                break;
            case R.id.img_add_address:
                intent = new Intent(FinalCheckOutActivity.this, CheckoutActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_left_in, R.anim.anim_left_out);
                break;
            /*case R.id.txt_add_address:
                intent = new Intent(FinalCheckOutActivity.this, AddUserAddressActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_left_in, R.anim.anim_left_out);
                //finish();
                break;*/
        }
    }

    private void getCheckOutData() {
        mJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObjectData = new JSONObject();
        try {

            if (mChBxSameAddres.isChecked()) {
                jsonObjectData.put("billing_id", mArrayListAddres.get(mSpnDefualtAddress.getSelectedItemPosition()).getmStrId());
                jsonObjectData.put("shipping_id", mArrayListAddres.get(mSpnDefualtAddress.getSelectedItemPosition()).getmStrId());
            } else {
                // jsonObjectData.put("shipping_id", mArrayListAddres.get(mSpnShipAddress.getSelectedItemPosition()).getmStrId());
            }

            if (mChkBxDiffAddress.isChecked()) {
                jsonObjectData.put("billing_id", mArrayListAddres.get(mSpnDefualtAddress.getSelectedItemPosition()).getmStrId());
                jsonObjectData.put("shipping_id", mArrayListAddres.get(mSpnShipAddress.getSelectedItemPosition()).getmStrId());
            } else {
                jsonObjectData.put("shipping_id", mArrayListAddres.get(mSpnDefualtAddress.getSelectedItemPosition()).getmStrId());
            }
            JSONObject mJsonObjectPay = new JSONObject();
            if (mRdoCash.isChecked()) {
                shippingPaymentID = "checkmo";
                mJsonObjectPay.put("method", shippingPaymentID);
            } else if (mRdoPayPal.isChecked()) {
                shippingPaymentID = "paypaladaptive";
                mJsonObjectPay.put("method", shippingPaymentID);
            }

            jsonObjectData.put("payment", mJsonObjectPay);
            jsonObjectData.put("shipping_method", shippingMethodId);
            jsonObjectData.put("checkout_method", "customer");
            jsonObjectData.put("onestepcheckout_feedback_freetext", "");
            jsonObjectData.put("accept_terms", 1);
            jsonObjectData.put("customer_id", SessionClass.getUserId(FinalCheckOutActivity.this));
            mJsonObject.put("checkoutdetails", jsonObjectData);
            //showAlert("place order array" + jsonObjectData.toString(), -1);
            //Log.e("Place order", "Data-->" + jsonObjectData.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String orderID;
    private String urlMain;
    /**
     * web service responce
     **/
    AjaxCallback<JSONObject> ajaxCallback = new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, JSONObject object, AjaxStatus status) {
            super.callback(url, object, status);
            Log.e("Check out", "Url-->" + url);
            Log.e("Check out", "Responce-->" + object);
            if (object != null) {
                if (status.getCode() == 200) {
                    if (mTransparentProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        mTransparentProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    if (url.equalsIgnoreCase(mStrAddressData)) {
                        try {
                            if (object.getString("errorcode").equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                                setAddressData(object.getJSONArray("data"));
                                //getFinalCheckOutData();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else if (url.equalsIgnoreCase(mStrGEtData)) {
                        try {
                            String now = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pay_now");
                            String due = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pay_due");

                            if (object.getString("errorcode").equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                                JSONObject mJsonObject = object.getJSONObject("data");
                                setShippingMethods(mJsonObject.getJSONArray("shippingmethods"));
                                setPaymentMethods(mJsonObject.getJSONArray("paymentmethods"));
                                if (!mJsonObject.isNull("items")) {
                                    setOrderView(mJsonObject.getJSONArray("items"));
                                }
                                mTvSubTot.setText(mJsonObject.getString("subtotal"));
                                mTvDiscount.setText(mJsonObject.getString("discount"));
                                mTVGrandTot.setText(mJsonObject.getString("grandtotal"));
                               // mTvPendingAmt.setText(mJsonObject.getString("pendingpayment"));

                               // mTvPayNow.setText(mJsonObject.getString("payablenow"));
                                mTvPendingAmt.setText(now);
                                mTvPayNow.setText(due);
                                getAddressData();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else if (url.equalsIgnoreCase(mStrCheckOut)) {
                        try {
                            if (object.getString("errorcode").equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                                //showAlert("Your order placed successfully.", -1);

                                if (shippingPaymentID.equalsIgnoreCase("paypaladaptive")) {

                                    JSONObject mJsonObject = object.getJSONObject("data");

                                    orderID = mJsonObject.getString("order_increment_id");
                                    getPaypalData();
                                } else {
                                    showAlert("Your order placed successfully.", 1);
                                }
                                //SessionClass.logout(FinalCheckOutActivity.this);
                                SessionClass.setUrerCartId(FinalCheckOutActivity.this, "");
                            } else if (object.getString("errorcode").equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                                showAlert("There is error in order creation.", -1);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else if (url.equalsIgnoreCase(mStrPaypAl)) {
                        try {
                            if (object.getString("errorcode").equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                                JSONObject mJsonObject = object.getJSONObject("data");
                                urlMain = mJsonObject.getString("url").replace("/\\/", "");
                                Log.e("Final url", "Url-->" + urlMain);
                                showAlert("Click on ok to continue.", 3);

                            } else if (object.getString("errorcode").equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                                showAlert("Paypal API call failed. Account not found. Unilateral receiver not allowed in chained payment is restricted.", -1);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                   // showAlert(getString(R.string.no_connection_server), -1);
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(MainActivity.coordinatorLayout, R.string.no_connection_server, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    //setUI(view);
                                }
                            });

                    // Changing message text color
                    snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
                    // Changing action button text color
                    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) sbView.getLayoutParams();
                    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
                    sbView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Set order view data from web servicie responce
     **/
    private void setOrderView(JSONArray items) {
        try {
            mLinearLayoutOrderDetails.removeAllViews();
            //mArrayListMethod.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject mJsonObject = items.getJSONObject(i);
                viewOrderData = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_chkout_order_listing, null);
                TextView mTvName = (TextView) viewOrderData.findViewById(R.id.tv_order_name);
                TextView mTvPrice = (TextView) viewOrderData.findViewById(R.id.tv_order_price);
                TextView mTvQuan = (TextView) viewOrderData.findViewById(R.id.tv_order_quantity);
                TextView mTvSubTot = (TextView) viewOrderData.findViewById(R.id.tv_order_sub_total);

                mTvName.setText(mJsonObject.getString("name"));
                mTvPrice.setText(mJsonObject.getString("price"));
                mTvQuan.setText(mJsonObject.getString("quantity"));
                mTvSubTot.setText(mJsonObject.getString("rowtotal"));
                mLinearLayoutOrderDetails.addView(viewOrderData);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please try to create a *Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable answer.

Comment: sorry i don't understand.please explain

Comment: Sorry my bad, this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve